# Find the volume of a shape using spherical coordinates.

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, spherical-coordinates

Find the volume of the shape formed inside $x^2+y^2=z$ and $x^2+y^2=2$ using spherical coordinates.

I know I need to do a triple integral but I can't quite get the integral limits.

Comment: What do you mean by "inside" the two surfaces? All four regions defined by the surfaces (inside both, outside both, inside one but outside the other) are unbounded and have infinite volume. Did you leave out a restriction?

Comment: Must $z$ be positive?

Comment: Inside both and yes $z$ is positive

Comment: I have tried the computations. They are very intricate, whereas we can derive the result very easily by substracting the volume of a spherical cap from the volume of a cylinder...